# Odoo 11 exception (Server application error "code":100,"message":"Odoo Session Expired","data")

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo-11

I'm getting randomically the following exception navigating in my website:

> Server application error {"code":100,"message":"Odoo Session
>   Expired","data":{"name":"odoo.http.SessionExpiredException","debug":
>   "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\http.py\", line 647, in
>   _handle_exception\n     return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)\n  File \"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\http.py\", line 307, in
>   _handle_exception\n     raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])\n   File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
>   11.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py\", line 87, in reraise\n     raise value\n  File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
>   11.0\server\odoo\addons\http_routing\models\ir_http.py\", line 340, in _dispatch\n     cls._authenticate(func.routing['auth'])\n 
>   File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
>   11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_http.py\", line 117, in _authenticate\n     getattr(cls, \"_auth_method_%s\" % auth_method)()\n  File \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
>   11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_http.py\", line 90, in _auth_method_user\n     raise http.SessionExpiredException(\"Session expired\")\nodoo.http.SessionExpiredException: Session
>   expired\n","message":"Session expired","arguments":["Session
>   expired"], "exception_type":"internal_error"}}

It is possible it is due this error? the 404 error is generated by Jquery:
GET http://example.com/68/68.xml 404 (NOT FOUND)

I tested cleaning cookie, restarting the server and also the db, but the error still persist randomically, but always after the 404 not found message.

the url is generated by javascript dinamically, any suggestion on how can I test (with javascript in qweb view) if the url exist, before try to load it?

Comment: Try to restart service of postgres and then run menu.

Comment: what you mean with "then run the menu"? I've already restarted the DB, but the error is still there.

Comment: Then try with going on db/selector page and again select db and re-login. Done this process in incognito window.

Comment: Is there any specific scenario when the error is getting generated?

Comment: I found the issue, it is linked to a javascript library imported in odoo, avoiding to load the url not found, the error is not triggered. thanks for the support